# ListView and multi-touch gestures

Tags: android, listview, gesture

Firstly, I realize this doesn't follow any particular convention.  I'm just wondering if it is possible.

I'd like to give my users the ability to perform an action on many items in a ListView.  My ListView items already contain a checkbox for something different; and adding another checkbox is not an option (it would look ugly?).

I was wondering if it's possible to programmatically highlight multiple items by determining which items were covered by a two-finger swipe.

This would require a few things:

1) Android's ListView would have to be capable of determining the difference between a two-finger swipe and a single-finger swipe.
2) I would need to be able to clarify which code a two-finger swipe invokes.
3) Ideally, if I'm two-finger swiping, and my fingers reach the bottom of the screen, the ListView would begin scrolling; so I could continue to highlight items that are originally off the screen.
4) The ListView would have to be capable of highlighting more than one option.

Number 4 could probably be hacked around so long as I could determine which items were passed over with the two-fingers.  I could hack together my own "selection."  After doing this, I would provide some functionality via the Menu button to do something to these highlighted items.

Does any of this seem possible?  What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 and #2 could be handled via `GestureDetector`, layered atop your `ListView`. However, that probably runs counter to #3. #4 probably would not be handled by standard Android "selection" state, but you could manually adjust the views (e.g., show a previously invisible icon, change the background color of something).

#3, though, really feels like it would require modifications to `ListView` itself, and that strikes me as being rather unpleasant, given the `ListView` (and `AbsListView`) code.

One way around that would be to interpret your gestures as additive (a new two-finger gesture does not clear the previous multi-select, but adds more to the existing one), using a menu choice to clear the previous selections. Then, the user can select some, scroll, select some more, etc.

All that being said, I suspect that this will not be very discoverable. You're assuming people will find out about the gestures by RTFM, and we both know how well *that* works. Having this as an option is cool, but make sure that whatever is done this way can also be done by some other more conventional means.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'll play around with it when I have time and I'll let you know if I come up with anything